# Is there a way to offset Visual Studio's function signatures list and member list?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Apologies in advance because I'm sure this has been asked before, but I had no idea what to call the windows I want to move so I didn't really know what to search.

If possible, I'd like to move the two highlighted boxes here more to the right of the screen so it blocks the code above and below that line less.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no option to change the position of those popovers. If your main concern is that you want to see the code behind it, a workaround would be to hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key for a few seconds so that you can see through the popover. Here's an example of how it would look like:

[image: Demo]

Another option is to hide it completely and then reshow it. The <kbd>Esc</kbd> key will work to hide both. Then, to reshow...

- Members list --> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
- Method overloads --> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: Ctrl + J can also reshow member list if Ctrl + Space doesn't work.